# Snort not sniffing any traffic except it's own

Tags: networking, security, snort, ids, ips

I'm currently trying to set up Snort on my local machine. At the moment I have 3 VM's: 1 with snort on it and 2 used to ping eachother.
Whenever I ping from one of the devices to the Snort-machine, Snort notices it and sends an alert. However, when I ping between the 2 'not Snort' machines, snort doesn't notice anything.

I've always been told that Snort would act like Wireshark and notice all the network's traffic. Am I wrong in this?

If it helps, this is the guide I used: https://upcloud.com/community/tutorials/install-snort-ubuntu/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Usually Snort and its alternatives are either used to transparently "pass through" (1NIC in -> 1NIC out) all traffic in front of a gateway or router or some such, or by port-mirroring some traffic and investigating that. In your setup you either have to set promiscuous mode so the Snort machine can even _see_ the packets, or you have to mirror all traffic to it. In short: you have to make sure your Snort box has access to the traffic it should sniff.

Comment: The problem is that my interface is set in promiscuous mode. When I execute netstat -i it says 'BMPRU'.

Comment: The interface of your Snort box inside the OS, yes, but VM-wise? What hypervisor are you using?

Comment: Oh that's indeed a solid lead! I'm using Virtualbox at the moment.

Comment: Yes, you have to set the promiscuous mode in the advanced network adapter settings in your VM options. Should be fine, then.

Comment: Glad you got it working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of VirtualBox you have to set `promiscuous mode` in the Snort VM's advanced interface options to be able to see the traffic between other VMs / different networks.